# How to run the python plotly script from the HTML script to get the line graph?

Tags: python, html, web, plotly, linegraph

I have written a python script using plotly library that generates the line graphs from the csv files. I want to run the same python script on the web page/ web app using the HTML script> I dont know how to call the python script to the front-end html page. Please someone help me to run the python script on to a web browser **dynamically** through the HTML script. I will update both Python and HTML script below.

**Python Script**

```
 import pandas as pd
 import plotly
 import plotly.express as px
 import numpy as np
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 from pandas import Series, DataFrame
 from numpy import nan as NA
 import glob
 from pathlib import Path
 import plotly.graph_objects as go


 p = Path(r'c:\Users\shivarad\Documents')  # path to files
 files = list(p.rglob('*graph22.csv'))  # get files



 fig = go.Figure()
 for f in files: 
     file_name = f.stem  
     df = pd.read_csv(f, dtype={'Pass Percentage': int, 'original_pass_percent':int})
     df = df.sort_values(by=['build ID'], axis = 0)  
     print(df.head())  
     fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['build ID'], y=df['Pass Percentage'],mode='lines',name=file_name))
fig.update_layout(title='Pass Percent VS Build ID of all the Test Suites',plot_bgcolor='rgb(230, 
230,230)',showlegend=True)
fig.show()
```

**HTML script**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <title>OV Daily Test Results</title>
<body>
  <form action="cgi-bin/results.py" method="post">
    <input type="Submit" name="show_last_runs" value="Display Results For Last 2 Runs"></br></br>
    <b>Enter Build id</b></br>
    <input type="text" name="build_id_2_runs" size="15"><br>
    <input type="Submit" name="show_last_2_runs" value="Show Results For Last 2 Runs"></br></br>
    <input type="Submit" name="collect_last_2_runs" value="Collect Results For Last 2 Runs"></br> 
    </br></br>

    <b>Enter Build id</b></br>
    <input type="text" name="build_id" size="15"><br>
    <input type="Submit" name="show_button" value="Show Results">
    <input type="submit" name="refresh_button" value="Collect Results" />
  </form>

<form action="toweb.py" method="post">

<label form="Test suites">For Bar Graph Choose the Test Suite:</label>


<input type="submit" name="Test_suites" value="Submit" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Please someone help me to the fetch the python plotly graph results dynamically on the web page. or suggest me anything that would work to get the results on web page.